# Why $ t=τ+n-1$ instead of $t=τ+n$ in n-step TD?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference-methods, notation, sutton-barto

If $\tau$ is the time, whose state’s estimate is being updated, and $t$ is the current time, then, in n-step TD method, we have $t=\tau+n$ (because we have to wait n-steps, before we can update). However, in the following pseudocode (Sutton & Barto's RL book, page 144), they have: $\tau=t-n+1$ which means $t=\tau+n-1$. What is wrong in my reasoning?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main detail that you are missing is that $t$ does not represent the "current time step" throughout the loop, but is just a variable giving a reference to a time step that you are processing.

The first statements in the loop are:

> Take an action according to $\pi(\cdot,S_t)$
> Obbserve and store the next reward $R_{t+1}$, and the next state as $S_{t+1}$

It is clear that after these two steps that the "current" time step is $t+1$. The value of $t$ is then just a reference to a particular time step that all the maths for the other loops is set up to use.

This in turn means that because the process has the values of $R_{t+1}$ and $S_{t+1}$, then it is ready to process the estimate for time step $\tau = t - n + 1$.

It would not really help to have $t$ one higher throughout the loop, because you would still need offsets allowing you to refer multiple time steps within a single loop. Instead of having the odd extra $+1$ you would see some $-1$s instead. E.g. you would need to take an action according to $\pi(\cdot,S_{t-1})$

You *could* swap the sequence of the two "If" blocks and have $\tau = t - n$ as the first statement.